# get dynamically width and height of an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I would like know how I can get dynamically the width and height of an iframe to use values at the loading of an other page.

**iframe-integration.php**

```
 <iframe src="iframe-model.php" scrolling="no" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
```

**iframe-model.php**

```
 var widthIframe = // Recover the width of the iframe, so 160.
 ('.element').css('width', widthIframe);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement

Comment: Thank's Teemu, you have give me the best way !